# how to instantiate a class from a class with its constructor and the parameters?

Tags: python, inner-classes

```
class A(BaseEst):
    class B:
           value_1 = 0
           value_2 = 0
           valid_3 = False
    def __init__(self, k_init, set_label=False, random_state=None):
           self.k_init = k_init 
           self.k_set_label = set_label
    def check(self):
         if len(self.buffer == anynumber):
               return 1
    

    """
```

how to call class B and the function init with all the parameters? I tried it but it says object has no attribute

Comment: Is that how your indentation looks in your actual file? As shown, class A contains nothing, and those are free functions, not methods of anything. Also please show the code you've tried, so we have a better idea what you want to do and what isn't working. And full stack traces are better than just a description of the error message.

Comment: Yes class A looks like this. Main question is to get the idea of how instantiating of such problem works?

Comment: if I delete the top line, which is a syntax error as written, then I can call B with all its parameters. Can you give us the code that generates an error?

Comment: I’m sorry I can’t, just want to understand how it goes without deleting anything.. I tried:
a =A( ) 
b = a.B( ) # like the idea of inner and outer class then 
b.__init__( ) 
This works but without adding any parameters. I want to add these parameters if you can help

Comment: The code you've provided *doesn't even compile*, it would raise a SyntaxError...

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: @Cooper It looked like your edit from 15 hours ago sorted out your indentation issues... Then your latest edit (5 hours ago) moved the methods (`__init__` and `check`) from class B into class A.

Comment: Voting to close because OP does not seem to know what her question is.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create instance of class A
a = A()

# Create instance of class B
b = a.B(10)

print(b.k_init)
```

Comment: how to get access to the parameters of class B ?

Comment: Methods have parameters. A class does not have parameters. Neither does a class instance (aka, an object). I have shown how to access a class instance attribute (b.k_init). I have already answered your question _how to call class B and the function init with all the parameters_. If you don't think that this answers your question, you should update your question to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried your answer - it's giving me this object doesn't take arguments

Comment: This code works for me. Please update your question to show how you "tried my answer".

Comment: @Cooper This works just fine for me when pasted after your code, as it was at the time this answer was posted. It doesn't work on the current edit, but that's because you moved the methods into class A.

Comment: How should it be in this case after the editing?

Comment: @Cooper It's now impossible, because your edit doesn't make any sense. Class B no longer *has* a custom `__init__` method defined at all.